# Dealing with missing factor levels in R function

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to write a simple function to adjust the exposed surface area of some geometric shapes depending on how they attach to each other. It looks like this:

```
funct <- function(A, shape, x) {
radius <- x / 2
A <- dplyr::case_when(
  shape == "sphere" ~ A - (pi * radius^2), 
  shape == "cylinder" ~ A - 2*(pi * radius^2), 
  shape == "ellipsoid" ~ A - (0.2 * A[which(shape == "sphere")] + (2 * pi * radius[which(shape == "cylinder")]))
)
  return(A)
}
```

This is simple enough, but in the actual data set factor levels are often missing, meaning that the the simple adjustments do not work:

```
testdata <- 
  data.frame(ind = paste(letters[1:10]), A = rnorm(10), shape = rep(c("sphere", "ellipsoid"), each = 5), x = rnorm(10))

testdata$Aadj <- funct(A = testdata$A, shape = testdata$shape, x = testdata$x)
#Error: `shape == "ellipsoid"... must be length 10 or one, not 0
```

I can manually get around this by completing the data set:

```
shapes <- as.vector(c("sphere", "cylinder", "ellipsoid"))
testdata <- tidyr::complete(testdata, ind, shape = shapes, fill=list(A = 0))
testdata$Aadj <- funct(A = testdata$A, shape = testdata$shape, x = testdata$x)
```

To make this a bit neater, I would be interested in some input for how to deal with the missing factor levels in the actual function. I assume this could be solved by first adding them to the data (setting 'A' to 0 to allow calculation), and then removing them again before returning the data?

I would also interested in suggestions for how to loop this across subjects ("ind" in the testdata df) in the function (as opposed e.g. to setting it up in a dplyr pipeline when applying the function).

Many thanks.

Comment: Try using `shape %in% "ellipsoid"` instead of `==`.  Not sure if that will solve your problem here, but I find `%in%` to be a more cooperative operator.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Using pure R seems to run without error:

```
funct <- function(A, shape, x) {
  radius <- x / 2
  sph <- which(shape == "sphere")
  cyl <- which(shape == "cylinder")

  A_new <- ifelse(shape == "sphere", A - (pi * radius^2), 
                  ifelse(shape == "cylinder", A - 2*(pi * radius^2), 
                         A - (0.2 * A[sph] + (2 * pi * radius[cyl]))))
  A_new
}

testdata$Aadj <- funct(A = testdata$A, shape = testdata$shape, x = testdata$x)
testdata

#   ind           A     shape           x       Aadj
#1    a  0.92219266    sphere  1.49043259 -0.8224824
#2    b -0.43705855    sphere  0.21633097 -0.4738145
#3    c  0.66549715    sphere  1.63981414 -1.4464310
#4    d -1.56945688    sphere -1.51169390 -3.3642633
#5    e  0.06975590    sphere -1.68775240 -2.1674572
#6    f  0.02811881 ellipsoid -1.04717409         NA
#7    g  0.95586893 ellipsoid -0.24831690         NA
#8    h  0.79428218 ellipsoid  0.03230311         NA
#9    i  1.86062696 ellipsoid -0.66786452         NA
#10   j  0.53938164 ellipsoid -1.26945744         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, this is helpful. I gave it some more thought myself, and realized that a very simple addition of an NA-aware function could do the trick with the rest of the syntax retained. This works better, because I would still like to go ahead with the calculation even if a factor level is missing. Thus:

```
sum_ <- function(...) sum(..., na.rm=T) 
funct <- function(A, shape, x) {
  radius <- x / 2
  A <- dplyr::case_when(
    shape == "sphere" ~ A - sum_((pi * radius[which(shape == 'cylinder')]^2)), 
    shape == "cylinder" ~ A -  sum_(2*(pi * radius^2)), 
    shape == "ellipsoid" ~ A -  sum_((0.2 * A[which(shape == "sphere")]), (2 * pi * radius[which(shape == "cylinder")]))
  )
  return(A)
}
```